# asp.net mvc5 project deploy issue on godaddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have uploaded an asp.net mvc5 prjoect on godaddy subdomain. The following error shows. [initial error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rT9N.png)

then i paste this code and after this code my site starting showing security error error.this image of the error is[erro2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rT9N.png)
 Here is my url [site link](http://royalbikes.ilegendtech.com/)

```
     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <trust level="Full"/>
```

my conig file is below

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
  <system.web>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>


    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RoyalBikes" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

its my first time uploading an sp.net project any help will be key for my success, Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post more details? How did you upload?

Comment: i uploaded all my files using filezilla

Comment: that is where you made the mistake. When you upload the for the first time, you should always use Visual Studio Publish, then onwards you can upload individual files in respective directory using filezilla.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/how-to-publish-Asp-Net-mvc-on-iis-mvc-5-0-part-3/

Comment: Inside your the web.config add the following configuration;

    <configuration>
       <system.web>
          <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
       </system.web>
    </configuration>

This will allow you to see the exceptions/errors you are facing. 

** MAKE SURE YOU REMOVE THIS WHEN YOU FIX THE PROBLEM ! ***

Comment: @dijam probably he did not upload the built code, instead he uploaded the source code directly

Comment: @AbhishekSingh if you think that is the case then maybe this tutorial will help - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/

Comment: i uploaded the whole project from the file manager of my project

Comment: @dijam i set Remoteonly but does not fix

Comment: If you look closely at the stack trace your web app couldn't connect to sql server.  I suggest updating your questions with the stack exceptions hope that helps!

Comment: @RanaAqibJaveed It seems that you haven't deployed your project correctly, please try to check this post http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/Cheap-ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-How-to-Deploy-an-ASPNET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-5cbin-Deployment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you use Trust level="Full" you need to impersonate the app to make request on behalf of the authorized user. You will need this settings in config where username and password is your control panel login to hosting.

```
<system.web>
<trust level="Full" />    
<identity impersonate="true" userName="godaddyuser" password="ForgetMe" />
```

Comment: if i use <authentication mode"None"> it shows an internal server error

Comment: Turn off the custom errors mode like this <customErrors mode="Off"/> . 'Internal server error' does not describe the real error

Comment: i did the same you can see this in upper web.config file

Comment: but nothing happens

Comment: The problem is with roslyn.exe file. Shared file hosts dont allow exe files to be uploaded. Remove the nuget packages  "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" and "Microsoft.Net.Compilers". and publish your code. It should work fine.